# post fixing u with an integer number in c causing a variation in atol

Tags: c

The code below is giving an output of 2147483647.
If the `if(atol(str)<=2147483647u`) is changed as `if(atol(str)<2147483647u)`, 
the output is 100.
The input is remaining same as `str= "2147483649"`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned long  l = 100;
    unsigned char str[19] = "2147483649";

    if(atol(str)<=2147483647u)
    {
        l = atol(str);
    }
    printf("\n%ld",l);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unsigned promotion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `atol()` returns a `long int`. But when your code is `if(atol(str) <= 2147483647u)` both the numbers are treated as `unsigned long int`. ie `(2147483649  > 2147483647)` and hence the output is `100`.  When the code is  `if(atol(str) <= 2147483647)` both are `long int` and hence the output is `-2147483647` which is the signed long of `2147483649` because  `-2147483647 < 2147483647`.

Answer (score 1):

INT_MAX = 2147483647

`atol()` returns a long

for numbers bigger than int max 2147483647

use `atoll()` instead

```
#include <stdlib.h>

       int atoi(const char *nptr);
       long atol(const char *nptr);
       long long atoll(const char *nptr);
```

Comment: I expect you meant `LONG_MAX`? Either way, if expecting `unsigned long`, I'd use `strtoul()` instead.

Comment: on my machine an `int` has 4bytes and a `long` has 4bytes, its the same, however you are right and so am i, your solution of `strtoul()` is neat and mine is practical

Comment: @mf_ If by practical you mean non-portable, then yours is practical.

Comment: The real code works on embedded devices where the header files are limited due to size constrains. So the stdlib.h is not added onto it.